# Restricted combinations (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm

Consider the following example:

I have a list of 5 items, each with their occurrence with either 1 or 0:

```
{a, b, c, d, e}
```

The restricted combinations are as follows:

> the occurrence of a, c, and e cannot be 1 at any given time.
>
> the occurrence of b, d, and e cannot be 1 at any given time.

basically, if found in database that occurrence of `a` and `c` is already 1, and if a given input is `e` (giving e an occurrence of 1) is not allowed (clause 1) or vice versa.

another example, `d` and `e` has an occurrence of 1 respectively in the database, a new input of `b` will not be allowed (following clause 2).

An even more solid example:

```
LETTER   |   COUNT(OCCURRENCE)
------------------------------
a        |   1
b        |   1
c        |   1
d        |   0
e        |   0
```

Therefore, a new input of `e` would be rejected because of the violation of clause 1.

What is the best algorithm/practice for this solution?

I thought of having many `if-else` statements, but that doesn't seem efficient enough. What if I had a dynamic list of elements instead? Or at least have a better extensibility to this piece of program.

Comment: You looking for a sql solution?

Comment: It's actually more of a stored procedure solution. But doesn't really matter, I need the algorithm to implement the code. I couldn't think of a good and efficient way to solve this scenario. I currently already have the piece of query to select the "solid example".

Comment: Is there a way to not select only the ones to exclude? Because I need the same query(result) to do a different thing. Meaning, I need all 5 letters to be selected with their count instead of only having to select `a`, `c` and `e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by BKassem(I think) in the comments(removed for whatever reason).

The algorithm for this scenario:

```
(count(a) * count(c) * count(e)) == 0 //proceed to further actions
```

Worked flawlessly!

Comment: I removed it because this will not work for: count(a)=1, count(c)=0, and count(e)=0. You will need to add more conditions.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It worked in my case, I needed it to be only 0 before proceeding. Therefore I have modified your solution from `!= 1` to `== 0` if you noticed. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.